# How to disable fsck run on Ubuntu 16.04 boot?

Tags: boot, 16.04, fsck

FSCK is running every boot on Ubuntu 16.04. How can I prevent this from happening? I've searched boot parameters and don't see any parameter setting this to be run on boot. Also, there is no `/forcefsck` file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `/etc/fstab`, for every entry, change the last parameter (a digit, usually 0, 1, or 2) to `0`

- `1` will run fsck first on this partition at boot
- `2` will run fsck next after `1` at boot
- `0` will not run fsck on boot

According to the [fstab documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab):

> Controls the order in which fsck checks the device/partition for errors at boot time. The root device should be 1. Other partitions should be 2, or 0 to disable checking.