# /dev/nvmeon1p2: clean, 226877/15237120 files, 4073338/60918272 blocks

Tags: boot, kubuntu, hp

[image]

Problem : `/dev/nvmeon1p2: clean, 226877/15237120 files, 4073338/60918272 blocks`

Note : this problem on "kubuntu 22.04.1 lts"

Laptop model : hp 255 g8

Comment: This is not a problem. The problem is probably unrelated. Describe in your own words what happens before and after you see this message.

Comment: I see the same message on my system when it boots. I would be curious why the message is being displayed, but I am not seeing any ill side effects from it occurring. Researching more today, I found this post which seems to have a potential resolution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/987024/boot-message-about-disk-clean-can-it-indicate-bad-disk Per guidance from @NotTheDr01ds, I would point out the resolutions in the post are not recommended. What I took away from the post is that the message being displayed is normal and should not be circumvented.

Comment: A line shown on screen during boot means it is successfull. The next task during boot is what causes an issue.Question: what did you change? video card driver perhaps?